# Print part of String with matching Index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a Program that takes a given text, checks to see at which indexes (") is located throughout the text and prints anything in-between the quotation marks (") i.e. "xyz" blablabla "abc". In this case, xyz between 0 and 4 and abc between 16 and 20 would be printed. I've got the indexes part to work but can't seem to find a way to print whatever's within the range of these indexes. Here's my code:

```
text = '"bleed" seed "deed"'

index = 0

a = 0

find = int(input("Would you like to find all the links in the file?\n If yes, enter 1:  "))

def Link_Finder(a):

    index = 0

    if find == 1:

        while index < len(text):

            index = text.find('"', index)

            if index == -1:

                break


            print('" found at', index)


            index = index + 2

    return index

Link_Finder(a)

print(text[index:])
```

I'm only printing the Indexes for my own reference. I'm quite new to Python so I'm not really familiar with complex stuff yet.

One way to do this in my opinion would be to return the Index values and then use the returned values to print the required text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using regular expressions, I think this is an easier solution:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', text))
```

If not, you can use your `link_finder` function:

```
def link_finder(s):
    index = 0
    while index < len(s):
        index = s.find('"', index)
        if index == -1:
            break
        yield index
        index = index + 2
```

And then iterate through the results in pairs

```
results = list(link_finder(text))

for start, end in zip(results[::2], results[1::2]):
    print text[start+1:end]
```

Comment: results = list(link_finder(text))

    for start, end in zip(results[::2], results[1::2]):
        print text[start+1:end]

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed the return key. I know results is a variable here, followed by a For Loop. Would you be kind enough to explain the For Loop, especially the zip part?

Comment: `zip` returns a list of tuples of one element per list, like this: `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) == [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`, and the [::2] [1::2] is called slicing, basically what it does is create a list with every other element

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much.